# The changes in tailwind classes nor stimulus controller in ruby on rails project is not reflected automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, stimulusjs

I have a Ruby on Rails project every time I do changes to tailwind classes or to a stimulus controller
I need to run

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
./bin/dev
```

I use yarn, jsbundling-rails [esbuild]
my procfile

```
web: unset PORT && bin/rails server
js: yarn build --watch
css: yarn build:css --watch
```

Comment: run `bin/rails assets:clobber` and stop doing `assets:precompile`. `bin/dev` is all you need.

Comment: Thank you I did `bin/rails assets:clobber` and it is working both tailwind classes and changes of stimulus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following to remove compiled assets

```bash
bin/rails assets:clobber
```

And simply use:

```bash
./bin/dev
```

as it will intelligently watch for changes and recompile only the changed files.